# QFuture then continuation never finishes (Qt 6)

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I have a question about `QFuture` and their continuation `then` API. Consider the following example code:

```cpp
auto future = getAccountToken("test@mailprovider.com", "password")
        .then([this](QFuture<QString> f) {
            auto const token = f.result();
            return getGameAccounts(token);
        })
        .then([this](QFuture<QList<GameAccount>> f) {
            auto const gameAccounts = f.result();
            // --> LINE NEVER REACHED (WAITS FOREVER ON f.result() CALL)
        });
```

And:

```cpp
QFuture<QString> getAccountToken(/*...*/)
{
    QPromise<QString> promise;
    auto future = promise.future();

    promise.start();

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://example.org"));
    // ...
    auto reply = networkMngr->post(request, doc.toJson());
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply, p = std::move(promise)]() mutable {
        p.addResult("<TOKEN FROM REPLY>");
        p.finish();

        reply->deleteLater();
    });

    return future;
}
```

The function `getGameAccounts` has the same boilerplate code as `getAccountToken`, except that it performs a GET request instead.
Does anyone know why I never reach the line after `auto const gameAccounts = f.result();` ? A single `.then` continuation works fine.
**FYI**: I don't reach the `connect` lambda for the reply in `getGameAccounts` either, which explains why I never have any result. But I can't seem to figure out why that happens.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems scope problem: Life cycle of local variables

Comment: Piggybacking on the idea of a scope problem -- what happens if you change the parameter variable from f to something else in the second .then? (basically wondering if there's some name collision in the callback context)

Comment: @dabbler Doesn't seem to make any difference. I also suspect a life cycle issue but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong? Am I misusing the API somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `QFuture::unwrap` (since Qt 6.4)
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuture.html#unwrap